# Sending TCP packets to proxy

Tags: go, tcp

I've familiar with `HTTP_PROXY` and defining a `DefaultTransport` to proxy HTTP requests. But I can't find anything about how to do the same for TCP. Is this possible? Or do I have to rely on on the proxy itself to forward the packet?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.  TCP proxies are possible, however, you can't redirect traffic based on the host because the TCP transport protocol does not include a host header like HTTP does.

Comment: Yeah, after reading more, I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible but not with an HTTP Proxy. You want a SOCKS proxy. Check out the https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/proxy package that provides a SOCKS5 Dialer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

var (
    proxy_addr  = "my.socks.proxy.local:8088"
    remote_addr = "chat.freenode.net:6697"
)

func main() {
    dialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", proxy_addr, nil, proxy.Direct)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "proxy connection error:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", remote_addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "remote connection error:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // communicate with remote addr here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this script hangs on dialing to remote address

Comment: @PrisacariDmitrii if you don't change the value of `proxy_addr` to a working SOCKS5 proxy, then I'd imagine it would hang yes. At the time of writing this and with valid values for `proxy_addr` and `remote_addr`, this code worked just fine.